# popup window changes location on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created popup window i.e. list to show on hover,it works fine for default page but if i scroll down popup also pushed down with scroll bar.

Below **HTML** code creates a popup list which is initially `hidden` and shown on `hover` with following **CSS**.

Sorry for posting everything but i tried changing `position`,`top`,`left`,`right` to adjust popup position as suggested in several similar questions but no luck.

```css
.dropv, .dropv ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropv a {
  display:inline;
  width: 185px;
}

.dropv li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 8px 2px 0px;
}

/* all list items */
.dropv li ul {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
  width: 185px;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* second-level lists */
.dropv li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

/* nest list under hovered list items */
.dropv li ul li a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropv li ul li a:hover {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<td id="' + frameoperationtooltip.concat(framecol) + '" style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="dataheight">
    <ul class="dropv">
      <li>' + operation + '<ul><li>Message Recieved(Bytes):' + writtenBytes + '</li>
        <li>No. Of Streams:' + readBytes + '</li>
        <li>Message Sent(Bytes):' + nbStreams + '</li>
        <li>Size of Streams(Bytes):' + sizeOfStreams + '</li>
        <li>Elapsed Time(ms):' + elapsedTime + '</li>
        <li><a href="javascript:OpenFileInPopup(&quot;' + request + '&quot;,&quot;' + preframerow + '&quot;);">Request</a>
        <li><a href="javascript:OpenFileInPopup(&quot;' + response + '&quot;,&quot;' + preframerow + '&quot;);">Response</a>
        <li><a href="javascript:OpenFileInPopup(&quot;' + callStack + '&quot;,&quot;' + preframerow + '&quot;);">CallStack</a>
        </li></ul></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: remove the position:fixed from .dropv li ul css class

Comment: @Nishad K Ahamed: if positon removed from css,whole list is shown at the time of page loading only.It doesn't hide the list but append the <td> contents with popup list

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
.dropv, .dropv ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropv a {
  display:inline;
  width: 185px;
}

.dropv li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 8px 2px 0px;
}

/* all list items */
.dropv li ul {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
  width: 185px;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* second-level lists */
.dropv li:hover ul {
  left: auto;
}

/* nest list under hovered list items */
.dropv li ul li a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropv li ul li a:hover {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<td id="' + frameoperationtooltip.concat(framecol) + '" style="display:table-row;">
  <div class="dataheight">
    <ul class="dropv">
      <li>' + operation + '<ul><li>Message Recieved(Bytes):' + writtenBytes + '</li>
        <li>No. Of Streams:' + readBytes + '</li>
        <li>Message Sent(Bytes):' + nbStreams + '</li>
        <li>Size of Streams(Bytes):' + sizeOfStreams + '</li>
        <li>Elapsed Time(ms):' + elapsedTime + '</li>
        <li><a href="javascript:OpenFileInPopup(&quot;' + request + '&quot;,&quot;' + preframerow + '&quot;);">Request</a>
        <li><a href="javascript:OpenFileInPopup(&quot;' + response + '&quot;,&quot;' + preframerow + '&quot;);">Response</a>
        <li><a href="javascript:OpenFileInPopup(&quot;' + callStack + '&quot;,&quot;' + preframerow + '&quot;);">CallStack</a>
        </li></ul></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</td>
```